# Steps of interpreting how this operation runs

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone could tell me step by step how these operations run. I'm not sure how they are being executed the way they are and I would like to understand. Thank you

```
 >>>s = 'Fuzzy wuzzy was a bear'
 >>>t=''
 >>>j=4
 >>>for w in s.split():
       if j%2 == 0:
          t = w[0] + t
       j-=1
 >>>print(t)
 bwF
```

As well as this one:

```
 >>>s = 'Fuzzy wuzzy was a bear'
 >>>p = ''
 >>>q = False
 >>>for ch in s[:5]:
        if q:
            p+=ch
        if ch == 'u':
            q = not q

 >>>print(p)
 zzy
```

If anyone could explain the steps python takes to interpreting this and executing it to get the results that it does, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Cordelia: You could simply put print statements in between to check the values that you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use python debugger pdb like so :

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
s = 'Fuzzy wuzzy was a bear'
t=''
j=4
for w in s.split():
    if j%2 == 0:
        t = w[0] + t
    j-=1
print(t)
```

With this, you will be able to execute your code step by step and print the values after any instruction. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)